# Excel formula: Matching multiple cells function

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I need help with a spreadsheet, which contains 3 sheets -

1. Preferred Warehouse
2. Top Scenarios
3. New Category

I need to be able to determine the correct category for a product, this will be based on a set of logic:

- If the Preferred Warehouse for an item = "PFS Kempston" but the top scenario = "Switzerland" Then the category will be "CH Temp from Kempston"
- If the Preferred Warehouse for an item = "PFS Switzerland" but the top scenario = "United Kingdom" Then the category will be "UK Temp from CH"
- If the Preferred Warehouse for an item = "PFS Switzerland" and the top scenario = "Switzerland" Then the category will be "Completed Listings"
- If the Preferred Warehouse for an item = "PFS Kempston" and the top scenario = "United Kingdom" Then the category will be "Completed Listings"

For example, SKU: 3M-LINT-ROLLER-RFL has a preferred warehouse of "PFS Kempston" but the top scenario is "Switzerland", the new category should be "CH Temp from Kempston"

The output needs to be in sheet 2. New Category

Here's some screenshots of how the spreadsheet looks like;

New Category:
[image: New Category]

Preferred Warehouse: 
[image: Preffered Warehouse]

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [SU] is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What have you tried already?  Also - your screenshots are to small for me to see.  However, if I am understanding your need properly, you should be able to accomplish this with a few Nested Ifs  http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/nested-if.html     Play around with that and post back any code you have tried and we can assist with working out the kinks

Comment: I tried this - IF(INDEX(ext!D$1:D$100000,MATCH(A2,IF(ext!C$1:C$100000="CH Temp from Kempston",ext!A$1:A$100000),0)) but Its incomplete as I cant figure out how to combine the logics

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a series of nested IF functions? =IF(AND(A=B,C=D),Kempt,IF(.....)

and just list out all of the different scenarios until one will hit true.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand it correctly on the New Category sheet you also have the column "SKU" and you want each line to be categorized.

This formula might helps, I checked the category of the item on "New Category" sheet in "A2" cell, wrote this formula in "B2" cell, then copied the formula for all the way down in column "B" - not that neat and compact, but it worked for me:

> =IF(AND(VLOOKUP(A2,'Preferred Warehouse'!A:D,4,FALSE)="PFS Kempston",VLOOKUP(A2,'Top Scenarios'!A:B,2,FALSE)="Switzerland"),"CH
>   Temp from Kempston",IF(AND(VLOOKUP(A2,'Preferred
>   Warehouse'!A:D,4,FALSE)="PFS Switzerland",VLOOKUP(A2,'Top
>   Scenarios'!A:B,2,FALSE)="United Kingdom"),"UK Temp from CH","Competed
>   Listings"))